# I want to remove apostrophe in a string, but is does not work

Tags: c++, string

I would like to remove apostrophe present in a string. I tried to write something but it seems that my syntax is wrong. I can't figure out where the problem is, but I know that something is not right in my syntax. I use Dev-C++.

```
{...
cout<<"enter the word to test "<<endl;
getline(cin,givenword);
string str (givenword);

std::string deleteapostr(givenword);
// trying to delete apostrophe if present in the string
deleteapostr.erase(std::remove_if(deleteapostr.begin(), deleteapostr.end(), '\'', deleteapostr.end());
...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `remove_if` requires a predicate for its 3rd argument, not an element value.  You want plain old `remove`.
2. You're missing a closing parenthesis for the arguments to `remove_if`.

```
deleteapostr.erase(std::remove(deleteapostr.begin(), deleteapostr.end(), '\''), deleteapostr.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

[remove_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/) takes 3 arguments, not 4, so your whole `erase()` line is messed up.

Note also that the 3rd argument is a `Predicate`, so rather than passing the character you want to remove, `'\''`, you would pass a function that returns a `bool` for the type that's being iterated over:

```
bool isApostrophe(char c) { return c == '\''; }
...
deleteapostr.erase(std::remove_if(deleteapostr.begin(), deleteapostr.end(), isApostrophe), deleteapostr.end());
```

**EDIT:** `std::remove` probably is better for this case, but I left it as `std::remove_if` since that's what you started out with, and it also gives you the option to change the predicate to something like `isPunctuation`.